# Do constructor object assignments leak memory

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

Say I have a simple class like this:

```
class MyObj
{
char* myPtr;
public: 
    MyObj()
    {
        myPtr = malloc(30);
    }
    ~MyObj()
    {
        free(myPtr);
    }
} 

class TestObject
{
    MyObj _myObj;

public:
    TestObject(MyObj myObj) 
    {
        _myObj = myObj;
    }
};
```

Does this leak memory? My reasoning is that there is already an instance of MyObj contained in the TestObject by the time the constructor runs, so doesn't that blow away the myPtr before the memory can be freed? Does assigning to a local object call the destructor of the object being replaced? Does the compiler optimize away the assignment of an object instance variable if it is directly assigned in the constructor? I'm coming from C# where an object doesn't get automatically initialized just by declaring a reference type variable, so this is kind of confusing me.

Thanks!

Comment: "Does this leak memory?" What does your C++ textbook have to say regarding this?

Comment: That both leaks memory *and* eventually double-frees memory. In short, you would be pressed to make this *more* wrong than it already is.

Comment: To not have leak problems or double free problems, you'd want to follow the [rule-of-5](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) . Or go the best route and use `std::unique_ptr`

Comment: Read about the Rule of 3/5/zero. Assignment might do something you don't expect/want there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does this leak memory?

*Yes*. The assignment of `myObj` will invoke the default copy-assignment operator, as no override was provided by you. As a result, a member-by-member copy is performed, and the `myPtr` instance of the assignment target is overwritten with the `myPtr` instance from the assignment source. There introduces two problems, frequently encountered when violating one or more parts of the [Rule of Three/Five/Zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three):

1. You lose the original `myPtr` content from the target of the assignment. Thus, the original memory uniquely referred to by that pointer is leaked.
2. You now *share* the same pointer value in two `myPtr` members: both the source *and* the target of the assignment operation.

The latter is especially troubling, as `myObj` is leaving scope immediately after the assignment is complete within the `TestObject` constructor. In doing so, `myObj` will be destroyed, and with that, it's `myPtr` freed. Further, `myObj` was passed *in* to that constructor by *value*, not reference, so an implicit copy is already likely to have happened (short of elided copy due to rvalue move semantics). Therefore, *three* `MyObj` objects may well be hoisting a `myPtr` that all reference the *same memory*, and as soon as one releases it, the rest are unknowingly hoisting *dangling* pointers. Any dereference or `free`-ing of those pointers will invoke *undefined behavior*.

> Does assigning to a local object call the destructor of the object being replaced?

Destructors are only invoked to live to their namesake. I.e., they're only invoked when an object is being **destroyed** (manual invoke of destructors for placement-new semantics notwithstanding). Copy-assignment doesn't do that unless temporaries are introduced, and that isn't the case in your code.

> Does the compiler optimize away the assignment of an object instance variable if it is directly assigned in the constructor?

No, but a [*member initialization list*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) can assist in that regard.

---

Modern C++ programming techniques frequently use [**RAII**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii) to accomplish what you seem to be trying in a number of ways, depending on the goal you're really trying to achieve.

**Unique Data Per Instance**

If the goal is unique dynamic data per instance, you can accomplish this easily with either `std::vector<char>`, or simply `std::string`, depending on the underlying need. Both are RAII data types and are usually ample for dynamic memory management needs.

```
class MyObj
{
    std::vector<char> myData;
public: 
    MyObj() : myData(30)
    {
    }
} 

class TestObject
{
    MyObj _myObj;

public:
    TestObject(MyObj myObj)
        : _myObj(std::move(myObj))
    {
    }
};
```

This eliminates the need to a destructor in `MyObj`, and utilizes *move semantics* as well as the aforementioned member initialization list in the `TestObject` constructor. All instances of `MyObj` will hoist a distinct vector of `char`. All assignment operations for `MyObj` and `TestObject` work with default implementations.

**Assignments Share Memory**

Unlikely you desire this, but it is none-the-less feasible:

```
class MyObj
{
    std::shared_ptr<char> myPtr;
public: 
    MyObj() : myPtr(new char[30])
    {
    }
};

class TestObject
{
    MyObj _myObj;

public:
    TestObject(MyObj myObj) 
        : _myObj(std::move(myObj))
    {
    }
};
```

Similar code, but different member type. Now `myPtr` is a [*shared pointer*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) to an array of `char`. Any assignment to a different `myPtr` joins the share list. In short, assignment means both object reference the *same* data, and reference-counting ensures the last-man-standing sweeps up the mess.

<sub>Note: There is the possibility of a memory leak using shared pointers like this, as the `new` may succeed, but the shared data block of the shared-pointer may throw an exception. This is addressed in C++17,
 where [`std::make_shared`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared) supports array-allocation</sub>

---

These are just a few ways of doing what you may be trying to accomplish. I encourage you to read about the [Rule of Three/Five/Zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) and about [RAII](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii) concepts both at the links provided and on this site. There are plenty of examples that will likely answer further questions you may have.

Comment: Thanks! Super helpful.